# create a session using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I am beginner in web development so please understand me. I am trying to create a session using php file and call it in javascript using ajax request. but after I input the path of the index.html in address bar, it always shows the index. I want to know how can i possibly do this with javascript and php. restricting the all the pages of the site if there is no user active.

for example logic:

```
if (userhasValue == true) {
//redirect to index and can access the whole website
} else {
// redirect to login page
}
```

I have tried the code below but it still redirecting to index.html even if the data recieve in ajax request is empty.

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();
   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   $temparray = array();

      $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select user_id,username,fullname from user where username = '$user_check'");

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($row > 0 ){         
                array_push($temparray, $row); //save your data into array
                echo json_encode($temparray);
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }

?>

function getUser(){
var user ='';
var fullname ='';
var id ='';
var tempArray = '';
var name = '';
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../bench/php/session.php',
            data:'',
            success:function(msg){
                alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                let tempArray = JSON.parse(msg)
                user = JSON.stringify(tempArray[0]['username']);
                fullname = JSON.stringify(tempArray[0]['fullname']);    
                id = JSON.stringify(tempArray[0]['id']);        
                document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = fullname;   
                if (msg == 'Error') {
                   window.location.href = "../pages-login.html";
                }                       
            }, error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }, complete: function(c){
                console.log(c);
            }
        });
}
```

The code above does not restrict the accessibility of the index.html and other pages if the user is not logged in.

I want to restrict the index page and other pages if the user try to redirect to index page without logging in.

Please help me. Any help will much be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be using [Prepared Statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared) to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Is your PHP running? If not, try `index.php` instead of `index.html`. It looks like the problem is with your javascript, though. Try `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_GET)` on the server. Is anything being submitted to the server? You may want to look at [`XmlHTTPRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: @Reed , where should I put the `print_r(something)` sir?

Comment: @Reed Sir? I have seen this on `console.log` may this is what you mean. `VM1202:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 79
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (index.js:33)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)`

Comment: I think that's indicating that `let tempArray = JSON.parse(msg)` is failing. `msg` must not be valid `JSON`.

Comment: `print_r(...)` would go in the php script that you're submitting to. So, it would be in `../bench/php/session.php`. And sorry, you don't need `XmlHTTPRequest`, because that's what `$.ajax(...)` is using underneath.

Comment: In you `success` javascript function, you may want to write (first thing) `console.log("response:"+msg);` or `alert(msg);` So you can see what the server is returning from the `$.ajax` request.

Comment: @Reed , if I logged in an account, this is the return value sir,
`response:[{"user_id":"1","username":"a.villar026","fullname":"Alexis Abulencia Villar"}]`

Comment: Also, there is no printed in console.log if i redirect only using address bar without logging in sir.

Comment: I'm off to bed. Hope you find a solution. If not, I may look over this again, but don't know how soon I'll be back on.

Comment: @Reed Ok sir. thanks by the way.